# Finding the average of numbers

Tags: javascript

Okay so I was given this by my friend to input 10 grades and have it output the average in a prompt. I'm very new to coding, and have no idea how to do this. Please help!

```
var i, number, average=0;
for (i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
    grade = prompt("enter code hereEnter quiz grade: ");
    grade = parseInt(grade);
    average = average + grade;
    document.write("number entered: " +grade+ "<br>");
}
document.write("after loop sum is: " +average+ "<br>");
```

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/mean.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a function to take care of it and then call that function so it gets run.

Like this:

```
var totGrade = 0,
grade = 0,
average = 0

function gradeAvg(n) {

    for (var i = 1; i<=n; i++) {
        grade = parseInt(prompt("Enter quiz grade: "))
        totGrade = totGrade + grade
        document.write("number entered: " + grade)
        average = totGrade/i
    }
    alert(average)
}

gradeAvg(10) //the number of grades you wanna input, in your case 10
```

Edit: Added some stuff that fits your case better.

Comment: How would I go about putting the average itself in a prompt box?

Comment: @Robert Not sure why you would wanna do that, but you can just put `totGrade/i` in a `prompt`, but a prompt expects an answer and I don't know what you wanna answer with. By the way, if you move things out of the function you should set a variable `average` that is equal to `totGrade/i`.

Comment: @Robert If you want something that pops up like a prompt, use `alert()`

Comment: The reason I wanted it to prompt the average is because the average is supposed to pop up after the loop is done. So after 10 grades entered It's supposed to pop up with an average. I'm not really sure if that makes sense, but your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Updated with something better.

Comment: This is word for word what it says to do "Output the resulting average with descriptive text" And the numbers aren't entering normally for some reason

Comment: I've double-checked my code and it should work. Just add some descriptive text inside the `alert()` and you're good to go. Don't forget to mark my answer if it helped you.

Comment: As noob as it is, how would I add the text? I'm sorry I'm so new

Comment: The same way you did in `document.write`. Nothing different. Just `alert("This here is the average: " + average)` or something along those lines. You should check out some JavaScript tutorial like W3Schools, they're pretty decent.

Answer (score 1):

Start by thinking about how you actually take an average before writing down any code.

(Grade #1 + Grade #2 + ... + Grade #10) / 10

Looks like you're missing one of these steps.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider making grades an array

```
var grades = []
```

Then in your prompt you can loop over as many times as you need to and divide the sum by `grades.length` to get the average.

Here is a working version of what you described with my suggestions.

```
var calculateAverage = function (classSize) {

    var grades = [];
    var sum = 0;
    var range = classSize;

    //prompt for grades
    for (var i = classSize; i>0 ; i--){
        grades.push(prompt("Enter the next grade"));
    }

    // Calculate average
    for (var i = grades.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      sum += parseInt(grades[i]);
    };

    average = sum/range;
    console.log(average); // You could also just return this value
};

calculateAverage(3);
```